# Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: STRING, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_ADD_OPERAND

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update a row in DynamoDB and add new column as well

```
resp = table.update_item(
            Key={
                'Pkey': 'key1',
                'Skey': 'skwy2'
            },
            UpdateExpression='ADD dateModified :input2, SET IsActive = :input1',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':input1': False,
                ':input2' : 'Test'
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
```

getting error in input2,
i have even tried as

```
':input2': {'S' : "Test"}
```

that doesn't work.

why exactly i am facing issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD - `ADD` works with numbers and sets.

> The ADD action supports only number and set data types.

Also there is a note:

> In general, we recommend using SET rather than ADD.

Since you want to add new values, `SET` is perfectly capable of doing that. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET:

> **Use the SET action in an update expression to add one or more attributes to an item.** If any of these attributes already exists, they are overwritten by the new values.

So you can skip the add operation and just use `SET`

However, depending on the python library you might need to wrap the values as `{"BOOL":false}` and `{"S":"Test"}`